# Lucene: Retrieve All Documents on First Pass

Tags: apache, indexing, lucene

I have a simple index in Lucene, and there's a query term which retrieves *no* documents from the first pass. Note that this means that Lucene does not even score any documents, not that no documents achieve a certain threshold score to be returned. I am wondering if there is any way to make Lucene retrieve and try to score all documents when given a query and/or any documentation on how Lucene chooses the documents to be scored?

Comment: can you give some kind of a use case what you try to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Scoring in lucene is a not that simple topic.

There's a pretty old documentation for scoring:
http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/scoring.html

or the newer one:
https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/package-summary.html#package.description

it's possible to add your custom scoring logic. But be aware that you really have to know what you're doing.